# Getting a SelectList obejct from a ListBox and placing into an HTML Selection List

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

Say I have a ListBox populated with a name value pair SelectList(myUsers, "Key", "Value"):

```
@Html.ListBox("ListReviewers", (SelectList)ViewBag.ListOFReviewers, new { style = "width:120px;" })
```

I want to double click an option in this ListBox, and place it in a SelectionList like below:

```
<div class="selectedEmployees">
  <select class="selectionList" multiple="multiple" name="AssignedReviewer"    style="width:120px;">
     <!--x.UserID, x.FirstName + " " + x.LastName) -->
     <option value=""></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Once this collection is placed in the above, I want to store all the values in another SelectionList Collection for later use.

Here is the start of my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#ListReviewers').dblclick(function (i, selected) {
    //double click on this value of listbox of type SelectList(myUsers, "Key", "Value")

    //store this value and text
    var value = $(this).val;
    //var empName = $(this).data[0];
    var empName = $(selected).text();

    alert(empName);

    //append an option element <option value=""></option>
    $('.selectionList').append('<option id="' + value + '">' + empName + '</option>');

});
```

I can get the value of the dblclicked collection object, but not the text of the collection object. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attaching your event to the `option` within the select itself. You can then use `this` to access it's properties.

```
$('#ListReviewers option').dblclick(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var empName = $(this).text();

    $('.selectionList').append('<option id="' + value + '">' + empName + '</option>');
});
```

Alternatively, you can use `clone()` and `append()` to move the `option` from one `select` to the other. This will save you having to worry about duplicate options being appended.

```
$('#ListReviewers option').dblclick(function () {
    var $newOptions = $(this).clone(false);
    $(this).remove();

    $('.selectionList').append($newOption);
});
```

Comment: When i use $(this).text(), it returns all of the text values from the whole entire SelectList, even though i'm using $(this). I also tried just $this. Also, I noticed while debugging, when hovering over $(this), it shows the whole SelectList object, but when i hover over $(this).val(), it shows just the selected dblclick value.

Comment: Have you definitley set the initial selector to: `$('#ListReviewers option')`?

Comment: I tried that, but it wouldn't execute on dblclick when adding 'option'

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your issue is - the code appears to work: http://jsfiddle.net/7cjD7/

Comment: I ended up going with the below code:

var empName = ListReviewers[ListReviewers.selectedIndex].text;

My reason being that I couldn't explicitly access the options elements inside of the ListBox, even though I could in the console window.. I still think you deserve credit for best answer. Thanks for the help Rory.